# How to trigger "Fire2" button using bluetooth controller of Google Cardboard in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I am trying to transform object into VR app using google cardboard sdk in Unity3d. I write a script and comparing input buttons on Update method. So my code is below.

```cs
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        onObjectDown();
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
    {
        onObjectExit();
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
    {
        onObjectExit();
    }

    if (dragging)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
        transform.position = rayPoint;
    }
}
```

onObjectDown() & onObjectExit() method are as follows

```cs
public void onObjectDown()
{
    Debug.Log(name + " Game Object Down!");
    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position);
    dragging = true;
}

public void onObjectExit()
{
    dragging = false;
    Debug.Log(name + " Game Object Exit!");
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = originalColor;
}
```

This coding is perfectly working on play mode on desktop. But on emulator only onObjectDown is executing. This means only "Fire1" button is pressed. Is anyone know how to get input from button "Fire2" & "Fire3" via bluetooth controller ?

For reference, my input setting in project is as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Button 1 on Bluetooth controller you can initializing with Input.GetMouseButton(0) or Fire 1 because it simulate display tap. But the other controller button simulate (in my case) back button on Android device, so u can initializing with Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape).

Comment: I am only able to get trigger from "FIRE 1" only.  I am using [this controller](http://amzn.in/bf4JLsB).

Comment: Try to use controller in other apps, what happens when you press  that button? And do you make app for PC or Mobile device? Your input settings above is for PC and MAC, but GVR SDK is  mainly intended for Android and iOS devices.